# The review list shows wrong number of pending changes

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues

Please see the content and most importantly time which is marked in the following screenshots:

1. **11:26:54** It showed me 2 pending document changes (**Screenshot 1**)
2. **11:26:58** Clicking on the link to review documentation changes, it showed there is **no pending reviews** (**Screenshot 2**)
3. **11:27:03** **I thought someone might have just reviewed those changes before me. Something like race condition. So to verify, I looked history** It showed my review which was done 5 minutes ago. (**Screenshot 3**)

**Either there is delay of review number getting changed (screenshot 1) or the history list (screenshot 3)**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This thing is bugging me too from a long time, but here what I observed for documentation review because I also didn't find anything related to it.

Whenever you do review for proposal it takes at least three reviews to reach the threshold, so you did your review that respected proposal will either implement or declined.

So when you vote your opinion, like to approve or reject, the review queue will then clear the list to your account, but still the proposal has not yet reached the threshold, so it still shows in the review queue to other users, the proposal which are yet to reach threshold when they acquire all three votes it will stop showing in number of changes, and the number of changes will decrease.

To defend my case, you can check the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history) that only your vote will not clear the review list. The proposal will still wait for at most three declarative votes.

I hope I explained what I observed and if developers or conditioned users will give the answer it will be much clear.